# c# oracledbtype.int16 throws error as value either too large or too small for int16 though value is 1 or 2

Tags: c#

i searched alot on net but did not found anything.
i am inserting records in oracle table.i ahev 2 column.1 is long and other is int.
my code is:

```
                Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter param1 = new  Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter();
                param1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                param1.ParameterName = "INCONTENT";
                param1.OracleDbType = Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Long;
                param1.Value = dt.Rows[i]["Content"].ToString();

                //System.Data.OracleClient.OracleParameter param2 = new System.Data.OracleClient.OracleParameter();
                Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter param2 = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter();
                param2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                param2.ParameterName = "INID";
                param2.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.int16;
                //param2.Value = 7;
                param2.Value = dt.Rows[i]["ID"];


                oracom.Parameters.Add(param1);
                oracom.Parameters.Add(param2);


                oracom.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

when id is 1 it works fine.when id is more than 1 ,it gives error as value either too large or too small for int16.Column datatype is int,stored proc datatype is also int.
please help someone

Answer (score 0):

How big is an Oracle int?

`Int16` is 32,767 in .NET and `int` is an alias for `Int32`, hence 32-bit and 2,147,483,648.

When you write `var i = 1;`, the variable `i` is an `Int32`.

I think you are sending an `Int32` into an `Int16`, which the provider perhaps cannot handle. Or actually it can since it throws.

Cast the values to `Int16` or change your data types to `OracleDbType.Int32` if an Oracle int is 32 bit.

Comment: Thanks for you reply.It worked when i did 'oracom.Parameters.Clear();'

Comment: Do you clear the `Parameters` collection before you execute the query? That essentially removes the parameters and makes most of the code unnecessary. I'm not sure I understand what you have done.

Comment: NO.i removed after execution of query.